# Should it be $\mathbb{N^+}$ or $\mathbb{N}^+$ for positive natural numbers?

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

Or do they give exactly the same result?

Comment: I'd use the latter, I don't think the former is well defined

Comment: Some might tell you it should be `$\mathbb{N}^{+}$`

Comment: Or, in Bourbaki's style, `$\mathbf{N}^*$`

Comment: I find such symbols very ambiguous and, if under pressure, I'd use `\mathbb{Z}_{>0}`. Anyway, the `+` does not belong to `\mathbb`, so it should be `\mathbb{N}^+`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has been solved with the last comment.